# How can I get numerical data from an sql query in Java Spring?

Tags: java, spring, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

Currently my repo class looks like this:

```
@Repository
public interface RepoCosmos extends ReactiveCosmosRepository<MyClass, String> {

    @Query("SELECT * FROM c WHERE c.Foo = @Foo")
    Mono<MyClass> get(@Param("Foo") String Foo);

    @Query("SELECT VALUE MAX(c.intID) FROM c WHERE NOT c.condition")
    Mono<?> getMaxIntID();

    @Query("SELECT VALUE COUNT(1) FROM c")
    Mono<?> test();
   }
```

The top query works fine. Neither of the bottom two work however. Both return an error mono so that running:

```
Mono<?> b = RepoCosmos.getMaxIntID();
b.block();
```

causes an exception:

```
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2023-09-13 07:37:45.672 ERROR 19908 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to execute ApplicationRunner
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:785) ~[spring-boot-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunners(SpringApplication.java:772) ~[spring-boot-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:345) ~[spring-boot-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1343) ~[spring-boot-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1332) ~[spring-boot-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
        at com.careerswales.urlservice.UrlApplication.main(UrlApplication.java:13) ~[main/:na]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: domain should contain @Id field or field named id
        at com.azure.spring.data.cosmos.repository.support.CosmosEntityInformation.getIdField(CosmosEntityInformation.java:317) ~[azure-spring-data-cosmos-3.17.0.jar:3.17.0]
        Suppressed: reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblyException: 
Assembly trace from producer [reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable] :
        reactor.core.publisher.Flux.map(Flux.java:6273)
        com.azure.spring.data.cosmos.core.ReactiveCosmosTemplate.runQuery(ReactiveCosmosTemplate.java:660)
Error has been observed at the following site(s):
        *________Flux.map ⇢ at com.azure.spring.data.cosmos.core.ReactiveCosmosTemplate.runQuery(ReactiveCosmosTemplate.java:660)
        *__Flux.usingWhen ⇢ at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker$ReactiveInvocationListenerDecorator.decorate(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:242)
        |_      Mono.from ⇢ at org.springframework.data.repository.util.ReactiveWrapperConverters$PublisherToMonoConverter.convert(ReactiveWrapperConverters.java:564)
```

How can I run a query that will return a number rather than a `MyClass`? I am aware there is a built in method for count() but I have a few more complex queries that I would like to be able to run.
I have tried having the return type be Mono<Integer>, Mono<Long>, Mono<Object> and Mono<Object[]> with similar results.

Answer (score 1):

From the [documentation](https://javadoc.io/doc/com.microsoft.azure/spring-data-cosmosdb/2.3.0/com/microsoft/azure/spring/data/cosmosdb/repository/ReactiveCosmosRepository.html) I understand that `ReactiveCosmosRepository` inherits from `ReactiveCrudRepository` which has a `count` method that returns `Mono<Long>`. It's likely that `getMaxIntID()` and `test()` will work using that same return type `Mono<Long>`.